# Unlimited 0 kb size file are creating in a folder

Tags: java

I have a requirement in which for the incoming every 15 soap messages in the wmq, i need to make text file with those 15 records and put it in a folder.

Along with this, if with in 30 minutes, if we are not able to receive 15 soap, then make the text file whatever the records we have.

In short, either make a text file with 15 records or with in 30 min, whatever thye criterio meets first.

I applies the same and it is working properly. But from the last 2 days what happening is, a no of files are creating in that folder with 0 kb size evenif my flow is stopped.
This is the timer logic i used:

```
private TimeOutBC()
{
    //Private constructor for singleton
}
public static TimeOutBC getInstance(){
    return timeOut;
}

public void schedule(int seconds) {
    timer=new Timer();
    System.out.println(timer.hashCode());
    currentTimeInMillis=System.currentTimeMillis();
    timeMap.put(currentTimeInMillis, timer);
    timer.schedule(new TimoutTask(), seconds * 1000);

}

public   void cancelTimer(){
    timer.cancel();
}

class TimoutTask extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {

        try {
            catalogueTransform.checkTimer(CatalogueTransform.m);
            CatalogueTransform.m=CatalogueTransform.m+1;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            logger.error("errro whle setting time for file",e);
        }
        timer.cancel();

    }
}
```

}

Can anyone suggest me, what are the possible reasons can be behind this issue.

Comment: I have seen that behavior before in an FTP environment; it turned out the disk was actually full.

Comment: Could you tell me that how u find the solution for that

Comment: Either clean up the disk or add more space of course!